# Passing a pointer to a derived class gives compiler error

Tags: c++, com

I'm implementing `IDropTarget` interface. When compiling the following piece of code the compiler gives me the error **"Error   : function call 'CoLockObjectExternal(CDropTarget *, int, int)' does not match
'CoLockObjectExternal(IUnknown *, int, int)'"**

```
IDropTarget * 
txtenum_droptarget_register
(
    HWND    wnd
)
{
    CDropTarget *pDropTarget = new CDropTarget(wnd);


    /*
     *  acquire a strong lock
     */
    CoLockObjectExternal(pDropTarget, TRUE, FALSE);

    /*
     *  tell OLE that the window is a drop target
     */
    RegisterDragDrop(wnd, pDropTarget);

    return( pDropTarget );
}
```

The class definition:

```
/*
 *  This is our definition of a class which implements the IDropTarget interface
 */
class CDropTarget : public IDropTarget
{
public:
    /*
     *  IUnknown implementation
     */
    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface (REFIID iid, void ** ppvObject);
    ULONG   __stdcall AddRef (void);
    ULONG   __stdcall Release (void);

    /*
     *  IDropTarget implementation
     */
    HRESULT __stdcall DragEnter (IDataObject * pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);
    HRESULT __stdcall DragOver (DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);
    HRESULT __stdcall DragLeave (void);
    HRESULT __stdcall Drop (IDataObject * pDataObject, DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD * pdwEffect);

    /*
     *  Constructor
     */
    CDropTarget(HWND wnd);
    ~CDropTarget();

private:

    /*
     *  internal helper function
     */
    DWORD DropEffect(DWORD grfKeyState, POINTL pt, DWORD dwAllowed);
    bool  QueryDataObject(IDataObject *pDataObject);

    /*
     *  Private member variables
     */
    LONG    m_lRefCount;
    HWND    m_hWnd;
    bool    m_fAllowDrop;

    IDataObject *m_pDataObject;

};
```

In my understanding `CDropTarget` implements the `IDropTarget` interface which in turn is derived from (implements the) `IUnkown` (interface) so no typecasting should be necessary.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]; what's missing from *complete* in particular is the definition of `IDropTarget`.

Comment: @manni66 Can you explain your comment? I can't see anyone claiming `IDropTarget` is part of the standard.

Comment: @Angew That interface is a part of Windows SDK.

Comment: My understanding is that you should use QueryInterface to convert between COM interfaces, not C++ builtin type conversion. Usually this would be wrapped in a COM-aware smart pointer class

Comment: [The code you've shown compiles](http://rextester.com/MOQ5001) (after all methods are stubbed out with trivial implementation). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement drag and drop, I activated the C++ compiler (I was using the C compiler before this). I am using a precompiled header. Without changing the source for this header I compiled it using the C++ compiler. However in this precompiled header the following define is found:

```
#define CINTERFACE
```

The IDropTarget interface is defined in oleidl.h:

```
EXTERN_C const IID IID_IDropTarget;

#if defined(__cplusplus) && !defined(CINTERFACE)

 IDropTarget : public IUnknown
 {
     ....
 }
 #else  /* C style interface */

 interface IDropTarget
 {
     ....
 };

 #endif
```

So even though I activated the C++ compiler (__cplusplus is defined), the interface was defined as a struct and not a class (CINTERFACE also defined).